# Python - multiprocessing threads don't close when using Queue

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, queue, python-multiprocessing

This is for Python 3.x

I'm loading records from a CSV file in chunks of 300, then spawning worker threads to submit them to a REST API. I'm saving the HTTP response in a Queue, so that I can get a count for the number of skipped records once the entire CSV file is processed. However, after I added a Queue to my worker, the threads don't seem to close anymore. I want to monitor the number of thread for 2 reasons: (1) once all are done, I can calculate and display the skip counts and (2) I want to enhance my script to spawn no more than 20 or so threads, so I don't run out of memory.

I have 2 questions:

- Can someone explain why the thread stays active when using `q.put()`?
- Is there a different way to manage the # of threads, and to monitor whether all threads are done?

Here is my code (somewhat simplified, because I can't share the exact details of the API I'm calling):

```
import requests, json, csv, time, datetime, multiprocessing

TEST_FILE = 'file.csv'

def read_test_data(path, chunksize=300):
    leads = []
    with open(path, 'rU') as data:
        reader = csv.DictReader(data)
        for index, row in enumerate(reader):
            if (index % chunksize == 0 and index > 0):
                yield leads
                del leads[:]
            leads.append(row)
        yield leads

def worker(leads, q):
    payload = {"action":"createOrUpdate","input":leads}
    r = requests.post(url, params=params, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
    q.put(r.text) # this puts the response in a queue for later analysis
    return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    q = multiprocessing.Queue() # this is a queue to put all HTTP responses in, so we count the skips
    jobs = []
    for leads in read_test_data(TEST_FILE): # This function reads a CSV file and provides 300 records at a time
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(leads,q,))
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()
    time.sleep(20) # checking if processes are closing automatically (they don't)
    print(len(multiprocessing.active_children())) ## always returns the number of threads. If I remove 'q.put' from worker, it returns 0

    # The intent is to wait until all workers are done, but it results in an infinite loop
    # when I remove 'q.put' in the worker it works fine
    #while len(multiprocessing.active_children()) > 0:  # 
    #    time.sleep(1)

    skipped_count = 0
    while not q.empty(): # calculate number of skipped records based on the HTTP responses in the queue
        http_response = json.loads(q.get())
        for i in http_response['result']:
            if (i['status'] == "skipped" and i['reasons'][0]['code'] == "1004"):
                skipped_count += 1
    print("Number of records skipped: " + str(skipped_count))
```

Comment: Just want to clarify something: You're using multiple *processes*, not threads, in the above program. There's a big difference in memory and message passing overhead between the two, so it's important that you're clear about which you're using.

Comment: It's also worth noting that because your problem is I/O-bound, you probably could use threads instead of processes and still get good performance vs. the synchronous approach.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is most likely because of this documented quirk of `multiprocessing.Queue`:

> Bear in mind that a process that has put items in a queue will wait
>   before terminating until all the buffered items are fed by the
>   “feeder” thread to the underlying pipe. (The child process can call
>   the `cancel_join_thread()` method of the queue to avoid this behaviour.)
>
> **This means that whenever you use a queue you need to make sure that
>   all items which have been put on the queue will eventually be removed
>   before the process is joined. Otherwise you cannot be sure that
>   processes which have put items on the queue will terminate.** Remember
>   also that non-daemonic processes will be joined automatically.

Basically, you need to make sure you `get()` all the items from a `Queue` to guarantee that all the processes which `put` something into that `Queue` will be able to exit.

I think in this case you're better off using a `multiprocessing.Pool`, and submitting all your jobs to [`multiprocessing.Pool.map`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.map). This simplifies things significantly, and gives you complete control over the number of processes running:

```
def worker(leads):
    payload = {"action":"createOrUpdate","input":leads}
    r = requests.post(url, params=params, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
    return r.text

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count() * 2)  # cpu_count() * 2 processes running in the pool
    responses = pool.map(worker, read_test_data(TEST_FILE))

    skipped_count = 0
    for raw_response in responses:
        http_response = json.loads(raw_response)
        for i in http_response['result']:
            if (i['status'] == "skipped" and i['reasons'][0]['code'] == "1004"):
                skipped_count += 1
    print("Number of records skipped: " + str(skipped_count))
```

If you're worried about the memory cost of converting `read_test_data(TEST_FILE)` into a list (which is required to use `Pool.map`), you can use [`Pool.imap`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.imap) instead.

**Edit:**

As I mentioned in a comment above, this use-case looks like it's I/O-bound, which means you may see better performance by using a `multiprocessing.dummy.Pool` (which uses a thread pool instead of a process pool). Give both a try and see which is faster.

Comment: This worked great, thank you. I did change this line:

    responses = [pool.apply(worker, args=(leads,)) for leads in read_test_data(TEST_FILE)]    

This way, it loads the entire CSV file. The old code loaded the same batch of 300 multiple times

I loaded 200,000 records and memory usage was fine. Indeed, the process is I/O bound, because the API I'm calling can take up to a minute to respond.

Comment: `responses = [pool.apply(worker, args=(leads,)) for leads in read_test_data(TEST_FILE)]`

Comment: So ... is there *no* way to safely shut down the sending thread in the parent process if the child process dies unexpectedly?